# Why do some people put a blank #include at the begining of C++ Programs?

Tags: c++

I've seen a couple of programs that have a blank #include at the beginning. I would like to know what's the purpose behind this?

Like this:

```
 #include
 #include <iostream>
 // include more stuff
```

Example Link: http://mkaczanowski.com/beaglebone-black-cpp-gpio-library-for-beginners/#important_methods

Comment: First time I've seen it (at least noticed it).

Comment: To prevent code from being [compilable](http://ideone.com/vnKohE) perhaps?

Comment: Stop downvoting, this is a reasonable question, and the only google results are not a dead cert at being correct.

Comment: Just a wild guess: The linked reference is an HTML document.  Maybe it was created using some HTML editor that silently removes invalid HTML tags and the author forgot to escape the angle brackets in the code?

Comment: The BeagleBone Black example could be faulty conversion to HTML.  The `#include "Header.h"` lines are complete, but `#include <iostream>` or equivalent might well appear as a blank include if the conversion to HTML is bungled.  Having said that, the HTML source for the section is: `<p>C++ example:</p>
<pre class="brush: cpp; title: ; notranslate" title="">
#include
#include &quot;GPIO/GPIOManager.h&quot;
#include &quot;GPIO/GPIOConst.h&quot;` so it is not completely trivial to guess where the problem occurred.  I suspect it is a markup issue though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I thought it may be an HTML issue as well, but I inspected the html source and there simply is nothing following the `#include`

Comment: C'mon guys. How is this a valid c++ question? It doesn't compile (I'm pretty sure it doesn't with even a crappy CPP implementation), period.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: As you can see from my update which I was making while you were typing, I agree that the HTML simply has nothing there.  But since it is invalid, non-compiling code, we can safely assume that something got removed from the actual source.

Comment: Some people make mistakes.

Comment: Do you have any examples which are not on a website?  Files you've downloaded from a source repository of some sort?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Saw your edit after I commented. Thanks for posting that html by the way.  I agree, something must have been removed before it was posted as it will fail compilation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not likely to help anyone for future research (besides for a particular crappy tutorial)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The preprocessor that spits out the formatted HTML code for the link you posted is buggy. Look at the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/mkaczanowski/BeagleBoneBlack-GPIO) and you'll see, it should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GPIO/GPIOManager.h"
#include "GPIO/GPIOConst.h"
...
```

As an FYI, the code you submitted can't compile. It is illegal in C++ to simply have a line that says `#include`. The compiler will expect a file to follow so it knows what to include.